# Rails 3.2 will not update the time used in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, time, scope

I have the following code:

```
@record = @user.records.where("question_group_id IN (?)", @question_groups).ready.order(:next_ready).first
```

The method "ready" is a scope:

```
scope :ready, where("next_ready < :time", { time: Time.now})
```

Here's the **problem**:

I need this algorithm to run quite often. It selects a question to present to the user. To select the right question the :time in the scope must be correct. But it's not. The system seems to be reusing the same :time over and over again.

This does not seem to be a caching problem as it does it when I empty the cache and in any case I have this setting in development:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of Time.now is only being set when the source file is first read, you must change the scope to use a lambda so that it is reevaluated for every query

```
scope :ready, ->() { where("next_ready < :time", {:time => Time.now}) }
```